# In MVC view page javascript file url not resolving

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I have one MVC view page in which I show different **links** and I am using ThickBox to show a different ***page*** when ever one of these **links** is clicked. In these ***pages***, I am using jQuery functions to do some changes, but I am not able to resolve the jquery file path on the view pages. I need to give absolute path something like "http://test.com/js/jquery.js". But is there any way to make it relative?

I also tried getting the host url and using <%=%> and <%# %> but none is working.

Any help?

Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is when you run the MVC app from visual studio? If so set you're MVC application's virtual path to start at "/" instead of the default that is probably your project name.

This can be done by right-clicking on the MVC project in the solution explorer > Click Properties > Click the Web tab > Type "/" (without the quotes) in the Virtual path textbox. Then use Andrew Florko's suggestion of leading it with a slash `<script src="/js/jquery.js"> </script>`

[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3765/virtualpath.jpg](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/3765/virtualpath.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like:

```
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/js/jquery.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try

`<script src="/js/jquery.js" ...`

instead of intellisence-generated path with ".."

`<script src="../../js/jquery.js" ...`

Comment: It's strange. Please, run FireBug and introspect your html layout. Does it show content of js file?

Comment: No, it is not showing any js content, I have to give absolute path to run the js code